# Pass data from one state to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Right now I'm using UI-router's states for navigation and NG-repeat (within a page) for listing artists. When someone clicks on an artist it opens up a modal view with more details and bio.

The modal gets the data from NG-repeat and Index...

```
<div id="{{$index}}" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="portfolio-modal modal fade">
<div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2>{{artistesItem.name}}</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary"/>
              </div>
```

What I'd like to do is pass the artist data to another page where we can get the full URL path for the artist bio so someone can link to this.

I've looked into a couple of docs and articles on the web and I've got part of my answer so obviously my code below isn't working as expected. The artist page opens but isn't passing anything as I get a screen with only the buttons. The console does mention ID as undefined but the URL is indeed showing the right ID?

State

```
  .state('artistView', {
      url: 'musique/{id}',
      views: {
          '':{ templateUrls: 'index.html'},
          'navbar' : { templateUrl: 'views/navbar.html'},
          'artist' : { templateUrl: 'views/artist.html'},
          'footer': { templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'}
      },
      controller: 'ViewOneArtist',
      resolve: {
          artistView: ['$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
              return $http.get($stateParams.id).then(function(data) {
                  return data.data;
              });
          }]
      }
  })
```

The controller

```
app.controller('ViewOneArtist', function($scope, $http, $resource, artistesUrl, baseUrl) {

$scope.artistesItemsResource = $resource(baseUrl + artistesUrl + ":id", {id: "@id"},
    { create : { method: "POST"}, save: { method: "PUT"}}
);

$scope.id = id;

$scope.listOneArtiste = function(id) {

    $scope.artistesItems = $scope.artistesItemsResource.get(id);
};

$scope.listOneArtiste(id);

});
```

HTML link passing the data. Then on the HTML page I bind with {{image}} for example...what I am missing?

```
 <a ui-sref="artistView({id: artistesItem.id})">Click TEST</a>
```

Comment: Looking into this on the web and might be a better option to use services to pass the data through a function, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ui-serf` should not use interpolation directive, as you wanted to pass id parameter to route, you should pass that parameter inside json like `{id: artistItem.id}`, this will create `href` attribute & that will contains url with `id`

**Markup**

```
<a ui-sref="artistView({id: artistItem.id})">Click TEST</a>
```

**Update**

For passing multiple parameter from the `$stateParams` 1st you need to register each parameter inside you `$state` definition

```
 .state('artistView', {
      url: 'musique/{name}',
      views: {
          '':{ templateUrls: 'index.html'},
          'navbar' : { templateUrl: 'views/navbar.html'},
          'artist' : { templateUrl: 'views/artist.html'},
          'footer': { templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'}
      },
      parmas: {
          'name': {value: null}, //set value it default to null if not passed
          'bio': {value: null},
          'image': {value: null},
          'facebook': {value: null},
          'twitter': {value: null},
          'instagram': {value: null},
          'googleplus': {value: null},
          'site': {value: null},
          'nextEvent': {value: null},
          'devisTechnique': {value: null},
          'video': {value: null},
          'authorized': {value: null},
          'exclusif': {value: null}
      },
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
          //pass URL
          $scope.name = $stateParams.name;
          //pass data for artist page
          $scope.bio = $stateParams.bio;
          $scope.image = $stateParams.image;
          $scope.facebook = $stateParams.facebook;
          $scope.twitter = $stateParams.twitter;
          $scope.instagram = $stateParams.instagram;
          $scope.googleplus = $stateParams.googleplus;
          $scope.site = $stateParams.site;
          $scope.nextEvent = $stateParams.nextEvent;
          $scope.devisTechnique = $stateParams.devisTechnique;
          $scope.video = $stateParams.video;
          $scope.authorized = $stateParams.authorized;
          $scope.exclusif = $stateParams.exclusif;
      }
  });
```

Above solution will work, though I don't think the way your doing is good enough. Better Approach would be create an service which will keep a track of this all parameter.

Comment: Thanks pankajparkar! QQ: Am I right to assume this should work as well in modal view? In other words getting a path URL in modal passing the arguments from the previous view (where I have my NG-REPEAT)

Comment: I've added some comments. I'm successfully passing the URL but the data isn't showing on the new page?

Comment: after your suggestion I changed my approach a bit to use resolve and passing the data to the new page. The URL does show the ID but still not getting any data in the page.